# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm using laravel 5.7. I have a users table with a column user_type where

```
0 = default users
1 = Professionals
2 = Facilities
8 = Employees
9 = Managers
10 = Administrator
```

And another column which is boolean is_premium which returns either true or false.

I have created a middleware for admin

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth; 

class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->usertype == 10) {
            return $next($request);
         }

        return redirect('/administration/dashboard');
    }
}
```

And i have used it in the routes/web.php file as

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'administration', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
  Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

When i visit the admin dashboard route it says

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I know there is something im doing wrong...what is it?

And im assuming to create middlewares for other usertypes too and use in the routes file. Is this the right way to do?

Comment: Just put redirect to another URL. Or show 401 error message

Comment: @YanDatsyuk I didnt understand what you said

Comment: when i redirect to the another urls which are not there in the administration group it works...

Comment: Change this line of your code return redirect('/administration/dashboard'); You are making recursive redirection... Just try to change 'administration/dashboard' to another URL, to another route.

Comment: @YanDatsyuk if i change it to lets says '/' it takes me to the home page of the site whenever i click on admin route. Any route i create in admin group they get redirected to home page...the user has user_type as 10 how can he manage admin routes. Im sorry im new and trying on my own

Comment: I usually go with false logic first. If not an admin, redirect to home or somewhere else, otherwise allow the next request. Also, I noticed in the previous comment you use `user_type` and in your question it is `usertype`.

Comment: @adam That has done the trick. Now if works...could you post that as answer so that i can accept it...i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try false logic first:

```
...
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( ! (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->usertype == 10) ) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
...
```